# Export sql query results to xml data file in oracle

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have an SQL query which returns two columns with data like this:.

```
State   Name  
------- ---------
Online  Terminal1
Offline Terminal2
Online  Terminal3
Online  Terminal4
```

Now I want to create an XML file with a SQL query runs. XML file structure must be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Terminallist name="xml data">
   <Value id="0">
      <Terminal>Terminal1</Terminal>
      <State>Online</State>
   </Value>
   <Value id="1">
      <Terminal>Terminal2</Terminal>
      <State>Offline</State>
   </Value>
   <Value id="2">
      <Terminal>Terminal3</Terminal>
      <State>Online</State>
   </Value>
   <Value id="3">
      <Terminal>Terminal4</Terminal>
      <State>Online</State>
   </Value>
</Terminallist>
```

I want to save XML file to a directory like this `c:/file.xml`.

Comment: For this you can write own software program which executes SQL query and save the results as you want , or you can download some soft which can do this for you.

Comment: Use xmlgen package generate the xml string in the desired format and write that string to a file using utl file package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution uses a WITH clause to generate the ID as you want, starting from 0. Using the analytic `row_number()` function provides a guaranteed sort order in the result set.

NB: `XMLRoot()` is deprecated as part of the XML/SQL standard but generates the version header you asked for. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB5041).

```
with cte as (
    select row_number() over (order by name) - 1 as id
           , name
           , state
    from terminals
    )
SELECT xmlroot (
  XMLElement(
    "Terminallist",
    XMLAttributes( 'xml data' as  "name"),
       XMLAgg(XMLElement("Value",
                         XMLAttributes(cte.id as "id"),
                         XMLElement("Terminal",cte.name),
                         XMLElement("State",cte.state)
                         )
      )
      )
    , version '1.0'   )
FROM cte
order by cte.id
/
```

Here is the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Terminallist name="xml data">
  <Value id="0">
    <Terminal>Terminal1</Terminal>
    <State>Online</State>
  </Value>
  <Value id="1">
    <Terminal>Terminal2</Terminal>
    <State>Offline</State>
  </Value>
  <Value id="2">
    <Terminal>Terminal3</Terminal>
    <State>Online</State>
  </Value>
  <Value id="3">
    <Terminal>Terminal4</Terminal>
    <State>Online</State>
  </Value>
</Terminallist>
```

As for writing the output to a file, that depends on how you want to call the SQL. Use SPOOL if you're running it from SQL*Plus and want to save it to a local file. If running from PL/SQL you'll need to use UTL_FILE and write to a directory on the database server.

Answer (score 3):

Answer:-

Table name: temptable

Data in table :

[image]

Query :-

```
    SELECT XMLElement("Terminallist ", XMLAttributes('xml data' AS "name"),XMLAgg(XMLElement("value ", XMLAttributes(rownum AS "id"),XMLForest(Terminal,state))))
FROM temptable ;
```

output :-

```
<Terminallist name = "xml data">
  <value id = "1">
    <TERMINAL>Terminal2</TERMINAL>
    <STATE>Offline</STATE>
  </value>
  <value id = "2">
    <TERMINAL>Terminal3</TERMINAL>
    <STATE>Online</STATE>
  </value>
  <value id = "3">
    <TERMINAL>Terminal4</TERMINAL>
    <STATE>Online</STATE>
  </value>
</Terminallist>
```

Thanks
Narendar

Answer (score 0):

Using the Oracle XE database as source data I'm able to export the employees table as XML as follows...

```
SELECT SYS_XMLAGG(
    SYS_XMLGEN(
        XMLFOREST(employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone, hire_date, manager_id, job_title)
    )
) FROM employees;
```

The XML will look like...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
<ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>107</EMPLOYEE_ID>
  <FIRST_NAME>Summer</FIRST_NAME>
  <LAST_NAME>Payne</LAST_NAME>
  <EMAIL>summer.payne@example.com</EMAIL>
  <PHONE>515.123.8181</PHONE>
  <HIRE_DATE>2016-06-07</HIRE_DATE>
  <MANAGER_ID>106</MANAGER_ID>
  <JOB_TITLE>Public Accountant</JOB_TITLE>
</ROW>
<ROW>
  <EMPLOYEE_ID>...
```

The CSV list of column names for XMLForest can be obtained thus...

```
SELECT LISTAGG(column_name, ',') FROM user_tab_columns WHERE table_name = 'EMPLOYEES';
```

Luck.