# Azure job to extract the data to XML format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I'm trying to build a Azure DataFactory job to extract the data from Oracle database to XML file. However Sink(target) in the Copy Activity of ADF does not support XML format.
How is it possible to achieve the above scenario

source:

idnt | col2 | col3

1234 | abcd | 1

1234 | asdf | 2

Expected XML output:

```
<AA_ITEMS>
    <Idnt ID="1234">
        <Col2 ID="abcd">
            <Col3>1</Col3>
        </Col2>
        <Col2 ID="asdf">
            <Col3>2</Col3>
        </Col2>
    </Idnt>
</AA_ITEMS>
```

Please suggest. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

As Azure data factory does not support XML format as sink, you can write a query to convert table data into an XML format in the database and extract it to a file.

You can also try using the query in copy activity source which returns XML format and in sink change the file extension to `.XML`

Refer to this [blog post](https://blogs.dhrutara.com/blogs/data_factory_sql_server_table_export_xml) by Ramesh Kanjinghat & [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41799981/export-sql-query-results-to-xml-data-file-in-oracle) link.